# Doctest and Decorators in Python

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators, doctest

I was trying to use Python decorator to catch exceptions and log the exceptions.

```
import os.path
import shutil

class log(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        print "Inside __init__()"
        self.f = f

    def __call__(self, *args):
        print "Inside __call__()"
        try:
            self.f(*args)
        except Exception:
            print "Sorry"

@log
def testit(a, b, c):
    print a,b,c
    raise RuntimeError()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    testit(1,2,3)
```

It works fine

```
Desktop> python deco.py 
Inside __init__()
Inside __call__()
1 2 3
Sorry
```

The issue is that when I tried to use for testing with doctest

```
@log
def testit(a, b, c):
    """
    >>> testit(1,2,3)
    """
    print a,b,c
    raise RuntimeError()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

nothing seems to be happening.

```
Desktop> python deco2.py 
Inside __init__()
```

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The decorated function (which is actually a class instance) doesn't get the `__doc__` attribute of the original function (which is what `doctest` parses).  You *could* just copy `__doc__` over to the class instance, but ... Honestly, I don't really see the need for a class at all here -- you'd probably be better just using `functools.wraps`

```
import functools
def log(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args):
        try:
            return func(*args)
        except Exception:
            print "sorry"
    return wrapper
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to copy the docstring over to your decorator:

```
class log(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        print "Inside __init__()"
        self.f = f
        self.__doc__ = f.__doc__

    def __call__(self, *args):
        print "Inside __call__()"
        try:
            self.f(*args)
        except Exception:
            print "Sorry"
```

The decorator *replaces* the decorated function, and only by copying over the docstring would that attribute be visible to anyone.

You could make use of [`functools.update_wrapper()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.update_wrapper) here to do the copying of the docstring, as well as several other attributes, for you:

```
from functools import update_wrapper

class log(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        print "Inside __init__()"
        self.f = f
        update_wrapper(self, f)

    def __call__(self, *args):
        print "Inside __call__()"
        try:
            self.f(*args)
        except Exception:
            print "Sorry"
```

Comment: Wouldn't [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) help with this?

Comment: @metatoaster: `functools.wraps()` (and `functools.update_wrapper()`) specifically target *functions*. As implemented, it'll work on a class too; `wraps(f)(self)` would do there.