# Doctest and third party decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators, doctest

I need to doc-test a method which has to be wrapped with a decorator that does not apply `@functools.wraps` or `functools.update_wrapper` to the method being wrapped. In this case, the doctest does not see the docstring of the method to be tested:

```
@third_party_decorator
def method_to_be_tested():
    """
    >>> method_to_be_tested()
    "foo"
    """
    return "foo"
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22866510/doctest-and-decorators-in-python) is similar, however, I cannot change the code of the decorator.

What is the best thing I can do?

Answer (score 1):

You may not be able to change the code of `third_party_decorator`, but you can wrap it once again to address the problem, and even re-use the same name if necessary:

```
def third_party_decorator(f):
    # badly behaved decorator, this removed f's docstring
    def no_docstring():
        return f()
    return no_docstring

old_third_party_decorator = third_party_decorator

def third_party_decorator(f):
    # replace third_party_decorator AND preserve docstring
    new_f = old_third_party_decorator(f)
    new_f.__doc__ = f.__doc__
    return new_f

@third_party_decorator
def method_to_be_tested():
    """
    >>> method_to_be_tested()
    'foo'
    """
    return "foo"

import doctest
print(doctest.testmod())
```

Answer (score 0):

A small meta-decorator to fix this:

```
def w(decorator): 
    def wrapper(func): 
        return wraps(func)(decorator(func))
    return wrapper
```

Use:

```
@w(third_party_decorator)
def method_to_be_tested():
    """
    >>> method_to_be_tested()
    "foo"
    """
    return "foo"
```

Or, monkey-patch it (do it only once):

```
third_party_decorator = w(third_party_decorator)
```